# Restricción CHECK con expresión regular (MySQL 5.6)

Tags: mysql

Estoy estudiando un poco sobre el lenguaje DDL y he estado haciendo algunos ejercicios de creación y modificación de la estructura de tablas, pero se me ha presentado un problema en un ejercicio que no puedo resolver: tengo una base de datos de una línea aerea en la que tengo una tabla llamada 'vuelo':

```
    create table p5_linea_aerea.vuelo (
    id_vuelo varchar(7) primary key not null,
    num_avion int not null,
    cd_salida varchar(25) not null,
    cd_llegada varchar(25) not null,
    costo decimal(5,2) not null,
    duracion time not null,
    foreign key (num_avion) references p5_linea_aerea.avion(num_avion)
);
```

El problema en el que estoy estancado actualmente es que se me pide realizar las modificaciones necesarias a esa tabla para que el id del vuelo acepte 2 letras + 3 dígitos (por ejemplo: TV345)

Investigando un poco encontré que podía utilizar el operador REGEXP para validar la entrada de datos de la tabla y escribí lo siguiente:

```
alter table p5_linea_aerea.vuelo
add check(id_vuelo regexp '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}');
```

Cuando ejecuté esas líneas no me apareció ningún error, pero al intentar ingresar datos en la tabla, en la columna id_vuelo se acepta todo lo que escriba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de la versión 8.0.16 de MySQL las restricciones CHECK están completamente implementadas, en versiones anteriores a esta, si bien la restricción se puede definir, al momento de ingresar o actualizar datos, se ignora por completo. En estas versiones se puede simular la restricción check utilizan triggers. Para verificar el número de vuelo para el ejemplo de la pregunta, que se requiere sea una expresión regular ([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}), la solución sería:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER p5_linea_aerea.validarVuelo BEFORE INSERT 
ON p5_linea_aerea.vuelo FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.id_vuelo not like '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Formato de id de vuelo no válido';
    end if;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Despúes se trata de insertar un nuevo vuelo, pero su id no corresponde a la expresión regular:

```
insert into p5_linea_aerea.vuelo (id_vuelo, num_avion, cd_salida, cd_llegada, costo, duracion)
values ('A12345',100,'Guadalajara', 'Aguascalientes', 500, 40);
```

Y se obtiene el siguiente mensaje:

```
 ERROR 1644 (45000): Formato de id de vuelo no válido
```

Teniendo así la restricción funcionando correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
alter table p5_linea_aerea.vuelo
add constraint ck_linea_aerea
check(id_vuelo like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

O prueba esto:

```
alter table p5_linea_aerea.vuelo
add constraint ck_linea_aerea
check(id_vuelo like '^[A-Z]{2}[\d]{3}$');
```

Ambos ejemplos deben establecer una restricción teniendo en cuenta el patrón de **2** letras mayúsculas y **3** números del **0** al **9** el **operador like** se utiliza para ver si el dato introducido cumple con el patrón deseado.

Comment: Hice la prueba con los códigos que me recomendaste, pero el resultado era el mismo: la tabla aceptaba todos las entradas sin importar si correspondían con la expresión regular o no. Entonces investigando un poco más encontré que aunque si es posible definir una restricción check con una expresión regular, MySQL ignora la restricción al momento de ingresar datos en la tabla. Es necesario utilizar triggers para validar de forma efectiva la entrada de datos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression

Comment: Vaya que interesante y mala noticia a la vez, ok gracias y saludos